# How to dismiss alert on back key press in android?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to close alert when the alert is present with back key press else the page will be navigated to another page. I've tried `alert.dismiss()`, but how to find out if the alert is present or not? I want also to do the same with `ion-select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this using [**`registerBackButtonAction`**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/Platform/#registerBackButtonAction)

```
this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
  try {
    this.viewController.dismiss()
  }
  catch(e) {
    ... no overlay component open
  }
})
```

To check if an alert is present, you can do a check to see if an overlay is present using something like this [**proposed solution**](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/6982#issuecomment-254702114).

Comment: Thank you @Und3Tow.This is what I did at end.
`let activePortal = this.ionicApp._loadingPortal.getActive() ||
            this.ionicApp._modalPortal.getActive() ||
            this.ionicApp._toastPortal.getActive() ||
            this.ionicApp._overlayPortal.getActive();

          if (activePortal) {
            activePortal.dismiss();
          }`

Comment: You mean add backbutton control in every page where ever I am using alert, actionsheet?

Answer (score 2):

**Ionic 3** way of doing it:

```
  showAlert() {

    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'My Title',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Ok'
        }
      ]
    });

    alert.present();

    let deregisterBackButton = this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(() => {
      // dismiss on back press
      alert.dismiss();
    }, 401);

    // deregister handler after modal closes
    alert.onDidDismiss(() => {
      deregisterBackButton();
    });

  }
```